# Java Tree present within java Table

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a simple Scenario where i want to expand the node of a Java Tree which is present within a Java table. This Java Tree is not able to get recognized when i tried to spy. it is showing only the properties of Java Table.

When recorded i got this below code.

```
javaWindow("sss").JavaTree("aaa").Expand "abc;value1"
javaWindow("sss").JavaTree("aaa").Expand "abc;value1;value2"
```

If u rerun the recorded code it is giving error.
I m try to just perform an expand operation on the Java tree which is present within a Java Table.

Kindly suggest on this.

Comment: It says thats It is not able to find the javaWindow("sss").JavaTree("aaa").Expand "abc;value1" in the OR.

Answer (score 1):

As per the above statement java tree should be collapsed, try this:

```
javaWindow("sss").JavaTree("aaa").Select "abc;value1"
javaWindow("sss").JavaTree("aaa").Expand "abc;value1"

javaWindow("sss").JavaTree("aaa").ExtendSelect "abc;value1;value2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Precondition java tree should be collapsed by default
Put a wait statement and directly try this

`javaWindow("sss").JavaTree("aaa").Expand "abc;value1;value2"`